# Adjusting rigid body properties for multiple object

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Using object tools you can make selected objects to become a rigid body active, passive or  calculate the mass. But if you need more how to adjust other properties for multiple objects like "enable deactivation"?

Comment: Are you looking for Physics > Copy From Selected on the 'T' menu?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I knew it might be something simple :)